# Pegar último registro agrupado MySql por ano

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Eu tenho a seguinte tabela

[image: Tabela Exemplo]

Eu preciso retornar apenas o último registro da etapa de ensino ordenado por ano_letivo, utilizando Laravel/MySql

Exemplo:
**2002** - 15 /
**2004** - 16

Eu estou tentando:

```
$carga_horaria = DB::select(DB::raw('ch.*'))
->from(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM estudantes_carga_horaria ORDER BY ano_letivo DESC) ch'))
->groupBy('ch.etapa_ensino_id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ano_letivo, max(etapa_ensino_id)  FROM estudantes_carga_horaria GROUP BY ano_letivo ORDER BY  ano_letivo
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja pegar a maior etapa de ensino de cada ano_letivo a consulta é essa.

```
SELECT ano_letivo, MAX(etapa_ensino_id) etapa_ensino_id FROM estudantes_carga_horaria GROUP BY ano_letivo ORDER BY ano_letivo DESC
```

Espero ter ajudado.